# Why running TickTick (windows) running in Linux using Wine causes "CreateDbFailed "

Tags: linux, wine, manjaro

While trying to run TickTick (win x64) with wine in Manjaro,

[image: CreateDBFailed, please make sure to run with admin priv]
[image: detailed error msg]

The app actually starts,

[image: Error in the TickTick app]

with this error,

```
Operation System Version-> 10.0.19043.0 ***** 
CurrentTime -> 01/30/2024 09:20:32 ***** 
Locale -> en-US ***** 
Device Location -> en-US ***** 
Version ->  ***** 
Exception Type -> System.NullReferenceException ***** 
Exception Message -> Object reference not set to an instance of an object ***** 
Exception Data -> System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal ***** 
 ->  ***** 
 -> mscorlib ***** 
 -> Void Throw() ***** 
 ->   at ticktick_WPF.App.TryGetLocalSettings () [0x0002d] in <8f90307ac9cb436e9f50ce70ac9eac5c>:0 
  at ticktick_WPF.Util.Utils.LogTaskTimes (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.Int32 maxMilliseconds, System.String startMessage, System.String warnMessage) [0x0008c] in <8f90307ac9cb436e9f50ce70ac9eac5c>:0 
  at ticktick_WPF.App.StartUpSafely (System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e, System.Boolean createdNew) [0x001cf] in <8f90307ac9cb436e9f50ce70ac9eac5c>:0 
  at ticktick_WPF.App.OnStartup (System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e) [0x000b2] in <8f90307ac9cb436e9f50ce70ac9eac5c>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <de4d51d88e3b4eea89a8d6a3a9854818>:0 
  at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall (System.Delegate callback, System.Object args, System.Int32 numArgs) [0x000e7] in <75de555cd62f40719584e76ba8a177cc>:0 
  at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen (System.Object source, System.Delegate callback, System.Object args, System.Int32 numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) [0x00004] in <75de555cd62f40719584e76ba8a177cc>:0  *****
```

TLDR; I think theres some permission issue with creating the database files in Wine, cause it actually starts (w/ Error).

#### So, Can anyone tell me whats exactly causing this Error & how to solve it?

---

I already tried copying-pasting AppData files from windows installation to my linux wine, But still the error persists.

(**why use windows when linux version exists?**
TickTick windows version has more features than the linux one. And works offline, which I need the most.)

Comment: You might probably want to file a bug with Wine [here](https://bugs.winehq.org/describecomponents.cgi).

As per their [FAQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ) - 

_Should I run Wine as root?
 
 NEVER run Wine as root!  Doing so gives Windows programs (and viruses)
 full access to your computer and every piece of media attached to it.
 ...
 ...
 As far as Windows programs are concerned, you are running with
 administrator privileges. If an application complains about a lack of
 administrator privileges, file a bug; running Wine as root probably
 won't help._

Answer (score 0):

There might be several reasons for that, check the following:

- Ensure your Wine prefix has the necessary permissions for database creation.
- Make sure the user running **Wine** has write access to the database location of **TickTick**.
- Use `winetricks` to install missing libraries - if any -.
- Test another wine version.
- Try backup the database and then delete it, and then create a new database to test with.

Also, check **wine** website for more info:

- https://appdb.winehq.org/
- https://www.winehq.org/documentation

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing with database or privileges. There is a library called Bugsnag in that application, and it needs a certain .NET library to run, and that seems to not be included in wine.

Your best shot might be to search for `System.Deployment.dll` on the win system the app successfully runs on and try to copy that to the directory where your app is started from on the Linux system (or where the other DLLs are).

By the way, it seems to be some self-updating library, so there might be other issues with it once it can start up.